# WordPress Get Current Logged-in users post or posts with edit link

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

Hi Want to show custom post/posts of logged in user as list with Edit button with shortcode if possible

After trying and searching so much I found one solution but it show link of posts in menu as item But I don't know how can i make it as shortcode to show on post/posts on page with edit link.

Reffernce Code

```
function new_nav_menu_items( $items ) {
global $current_user;    
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'job_listing',
    'author'         => $current_user->ID,
    'status'         => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 1
    );
$jobs = get_posts( $args );
$link = '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $jobs->ID ) . '">Your Job</a></li>';
// add link to the end of the menu
$items = $items . $link;
return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'new_nav_menu_items' );
```

> Credit: Daniel C
>
> Original Answer at
>   [Get post ID of current logged in user and add a link to the menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685396/get-post-id-of-current-logged-in-user-and-add-a-link-to-the-menu)

I thankful if you spare some time and answer my this small question

Thanks in Advance.

---

**Final Answer**

> Credit: **Elvine** https://stackoverflow.com/users/701666/elvin85

```
function user_items( ) {
if (!is_user_logged_in()) return;
$items='';   
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'ait-item',
    'author'         => get_current_user_id(),
    'status'         => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10
    );
$jobs = get_posts( $args );
foreach($jobs as $job){
  $link = '<a href="'.home_url('wp-admin/post.php?post='.$job->ID.'&action=edit').'">UPDATE YOUR VENU AND OFFERS</a> </BR>'; 
  $items = $items . $link;
  }
return $items;
}
add_shortcode( 'your_job', 'user_items' ); 

 //usage  in post content [your_job]
//usage inside code do_shortcode('[your_job]');
```

Comment: `After trying and searching so much` Yet your code contains nothing about a shortcode?

Comment: Shortcodes are extremely simple to set up. See the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/)

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment .... Here i not only searching for shortcode ... but Instead just links of post i want edit link of post / posts of logged-in author

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function user_items( ) {
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) return;
    $items='';   
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'job_listing',
        'author'         => wp_get_current_user(),
        'status'         => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 1
        );
    $jobs = get_posts( $args );
    foreach($jobs as $job){
      $link = '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $jobs->ID ) . '">'.$jobs->post_title.'</a></li>';
      $items = $items . $link;
      }
    return $items;
    }
    add_shortcode( 'your_job', 'user_items' );

//usage  in post content [your_job]
//usage inside code do_shortcode('[your_job]');
```

Comment: Thank you Elvin for reply but i facing small issue error in result "Object of class WP_User could not be converted to string "

Comment: So sorry, instead of wp_get_current_user()  use  this function in my code: get_current_user_id()

Comment: Sorry again :) not worked am I doing anything wrong please check the question I Updated some results

Comment: please replace jobs with job in this line

$link = '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $job->ID ) . '">'.$job->post_title.'</a></li>';

Comment: "// " after domain and I got link to read post ... I need Link to edit the post

Comment: echo '<a href="'.home_url('wp-admin/post.php?post='.$job->ID.'&action=edit').'">Edit</a>';

Comment: Hi Elvin... Problem Solved.... There was extra "Echo" gave me error in your last suggestion but i removed it now working fine.... you really Help me lot... Thank you so much For you kind help and efforts

Comment: yes, that was common example, i though you would get the idea and remove it. :) i am glad the problem is solved now. you can mark the answer as a solution

Comment: Sorry I not expert as you :).... Yes I updated the question with correct answer... Again Thanks you